# Java 8 + Spring + JPA: IllegalArgumentException when one-to-one relationship uses a wrapper-type as ID

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm using Java 8, Spring 4 and JPA.

I have two entities: `Permission` and `RolePermission`, they have a One-to-One relationship through the `permission.id` and `rolePermission.permission_id` database fields.

So `RolePermission` has a `Permission` as "foreign key", but `Permission` has a `String` as id.

It is a bit unusual, but due to business logic, I had to map it this way.
Firstly Permission

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions")
public class Permission implements Serializable{

    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Permission (String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Permission() {}

    @Id
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = RolePermission.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setId(Permission p) {
        this.id = p.getId();
    }
    public void setId(RolePermission r) {
        this.id = r.getPermission().getId();
    }

}
```

and RolePermission

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_permissions")
public class RolePermission implements Serializable {
    private String role;

    private Permission permission;

    public RolePermission(String role, Permission permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
        this.role = role;
    }

    protected RolePermission() {}

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "permission_id")
    public Permission getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }

    public void setPermission(Permission permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I query it from my Repository, I get the following exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.ifood.next.models.Permission.id (expected type = java.lang.String)]; target = [com.ifood.next.models.Permission@551aa6a7], property value = [com.ifood.next.models.RolePermission@672da0e9] setter of com.ifood.next.models.Permission.id; nested exception is IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.ifood.next.models.Permission.id (expected type = java.lang.String)]; target = [com.ifood.next.models.Permission@551aa6a7], property value = [com.ifood.next.models.RolePermission@672da0e9]
```

As I understand it, when JPA is trying to create the `Permission` object to add to `RolePermission`, it is setting the id using a `Permission` object. But it is a `String` type!

So I tried adding the redundant setter (that receive a `String`, a `Permission`, and even a `RolePermission`), to no success...

Any thoughts on how I should model this to make it work?

Comment: You cannot put `@OneToOne` on a String field. A relation in O-O is between two objects, not an object and some String

Comment: Even if I set `targetEntity` ? What would be an alternative then?

Comment: The field is DEFINED by the type of the field (or property). String. targetEntity is just to allow people to restrict to subclasses, or to have an interface field and restrict to an implementation. Alternative? Put the right type on the field so it is a relation, just like you'll find in every JPA tutorial out there

Comment: I just want my `RolePermission` to be populated with the appropriate `Permission`... I don't see why the types are wrong? I don't want a `RolePermission` in the `Permission` class, as the field is the primary key.  I think my problem is with the mapping, but I cant put my finger on what's wrong.

Comment: You cannot have `@OneToOne` on a String field, remove that side. If you want it to be BIDIRECTIONAL you put a RolePermission in the Permission class instead of String.